# Wine error ubuntu GNOME16.04

Tags: 16.04, wine

I'm using ubuntu GNOME 16.04.

first I installed the latest stable version of wine but I couldn't start exe files by just double clicking. So I tried running the exe file from a terminal.

```
ren@TheMostWantedNetwork:/media/ren/BA320_2/Ad stuff/WIN SOFTWARE$ wine OpenToonzSetup.exe 
fixme:winediag:start_process Wine Staging 2.21 is a testing version containing experimental patches.
fixme:winediag:start_process Please mention your exact version when filing bug reports on winehq.org.
fixme:actctx:parse_depend_manifests Could not find dependent assembly L"Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls" (6.0.0.0)
err:module:attach_process_dlls "comctl32.dll" failed to initialize, aborting
err:module:LdrInitializeThunk Main exe initialization for L"Z:\\media  \\ren\\BA320_2\\Ad stuff\\WIN SOFTWARE\\OpenToonzSetup.exe" failed, status c0000005
```

I thought there was a issue with the software. So, I tried the same thing with  another exe file but it displayed the same error

```
ren@TheMostWantedNetwork:/media/ren/BA320_2/Ad stuff/WIN SOFTWARE$ wine sai-1.2.5-ful-en.exe 
fixme:winediag:start_process Wine Staging 2.21 is a testing version containing experimental patches.
fixme:winediag:start_process Please mention your exact version when filing bug reports on winehq.org.
fixme:actctx:parse_depend_manifests Could not find dependent assembly L"Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls" (6.0.0.0)
err:module:attach_process_dlls "comctl32.dll" failed to initialize, aborting
err:module:LdrInitializeThunk Main exe initialization for L"Z:\\media\\ren\\BA320_2\\Ad stuff\\WIN SOFTWARE\\sai-1.2.5-ful-en.exe" failed, status c0000005
```

So I tried starting winecfg it also displayed a error.

```
ren@TheMostWantedNetwork:/media/ren/BA320_2/Ad stuff/WIN SOFTWARE$ winecfg
fixme:winediag:start_process Wine Staging 2.21 is a testing version containing experimental patches.
fixme:winediag:start_process Please mention your exact version when filing bug reports on winehq.org.
err:module:attach_process_dlls "comctl32.dll" failed to initialize, aborting
err:module:LdrInitializeThunk Main exe initialization for L"C:\\windows\\system32\\winecfg.exe" failed, status c0000005
```

Same thimg with the older versions of wine. What should i do?

(Sorry if their are grammatical mistakes.)

Answer (score 0):

Late to answer but one way to find out if wine is at fault or the app is at fault is just starting wine itself without an argument... so this command should open a Microsoft Windows dos box/debugger box.

wine start

If the app fail beyond that, you're on your own.

Comment: As a community it is important to communicate in a manor that is consistent with [respectful discourse](https://askubuntu.com/help/be-nice). Your final sentence could be interpreted as not fully consistent with those goals. - [From Review](https://askubuntu.com/review/first-posts/788430)